# php file not loading correctly displaying blank page

Tags: php, html, linux

I have a php file called Choice.php and it is suppose to display html contents. I am running it on a linux server.  I set the permissions to 700 and when I try to access the choice.php file by url I get a blank page. I cant seem to figure out why this is the case. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
echo "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\"\n"; 
echo "    \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n"; 
echo "\n"; 
echo "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n"; 
echo "<head>\n"; 
echo "  <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\n"; 
echo "  \"text/html; charset=us-ascii\" />\n"; 
echo "\n"; 
echo "  <title>Choose</title>\n"; 
echo "</head>\n"; 
echo "\n"; 
echo "<body>\n"; 
echo "  <form action=\"index.php\" method=\"post\" enctype=\n"; 
echo "  \"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\">\n"; 
echo "    <h1>Choose</h1>\n"; 
echo "\n"; 
echo "    <p><input type=\"radio\" name=\"Radio\" value=\"1\" /><font size=\"5\"\n"; 
echo "    color=\"#0033CC\">Instant Psychology</font><br />\n"; 
echo "    <br />\n"; 
echo "    <input type=\"radio\" name=\"Radio\" value=\"2\" /><font size=\"5\"\n"; 
echo "    color=\"#CC0000\">Instant Geography</font><br />\n"; 
echo "    <br />\n"; 
echo "    <input type=\"radio\" name=\"Radio\" value=\"3\" /><font size=\"5\"\n"; 
echo "    color=\"#660033\">Instant Gastronomy</font><br />\n"; 
echo "    <br />\n"; 
echo "    <input type=\"submit\" name=\"Submit\" value=\"Go\" /></p>\n"; 
echo "  </form>\n"; 
echo "</body>\n";   
echo "</html>\n"; 
echo "\n";
?>
```

Comment: You do know you can just put straight HTML in a .php file outside the `<?php ?>` blocks, right?

Comment: As @MarkParnell said, you code is a little bit horrible to read. Append PHP tags only for PHP content, do not echo all the HTML, write directly the HTML in the page. Secondly, by setting permission to `700`, you give full access for you but nothing for the group and nothing for other. Maybe the Apache/PHP user is on another group and then, cannot have read access to your file. Try with `744` and tell us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file needs to have read rights for `other`/`world` to be accessible by through a webserver (i.e. by use of url). The reason for this is both so that the webserver can read the given file, and so it's accessible to the web. When using `700` it's only accessible for the owner of the file. `644` is what you want for (most) files, and `755` for directories.

Proper rights would be (`tim` being my user name):

```
$ ls -l Choice.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim tim    0 19.04.13 06:14 Choice.php
```

Take a look at [Linux file permissions](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/filepermissions.html) at Tuxfiles.org

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your Apache and PHP configuration on your Linux server, as it seems to be bad. It works 100% fine on my Debian LAMP install. Check your error log file to see if it shows anything regarding the page and time accessed. Try changing the permissions around, until it works for you.

Comment: Depending on the webserver, `700` won't work unless you made the file with the user of the webserver, for example `www-data` when using Apache. There is probably nothing "bad" with the configuration, and working just as intended.